# Python/Flask How to use the URL as a variable that links to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, url, flask

I'm new to Flask so I'll do my best to explain myself.

I am creating a quiz app using Python/Flask. Basically I would like my HTML template to show a question based on the question number found in the URL.

I have my questions and answers stored in a dictionary of tuples like so:

`[{question 1, answer 1}, {question 2, answer 2}, {question 3, answer 3}]...`

I want my structure to look like this:

```
@app.route('/<username>/<question_number>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def ask_questions(question_number):
    questions = get_all_questions()
    return render_template("riddle1.html", question=questions, question_number=1)
```

Note the get_all_questions() function returns the dictionary of questions/answers.

HTML:

```html
<body>
    <h1>Welcome, {{ username }} to RiddleMeThis!</h1>

    <p>{{ question[i][0] }}</p>

    <form method="POST">
        <label for="guess">Answer:</label>
        <input type="text" id="guess" name="guess">
        <button>Enter</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

The idea is that if the URL for  is 1, it pulls the question from the dictionary of tuples which would be [0][0]. For question 2, [1][0], for question 3 [2][0] and so on.

Upon answering the page would redirect to a page that compares the user answer to the answer in the tuple. If correct, it is redirected to the last page but with the  now equalling 2, if incorrect it is simply taken back to the last page.

I have taken a few spins at this and am really struggling to work out how to first plug the number into the URL and then also link that number to the dictionary - completely lost!!

Is anyone able to point me in a direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to be looking into forms and `url_for()`. There's quite a bit of ground to cover to pull this together from what you've given us so you may want to try playing around yourself some more first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if i got it right or not.

But I'll give it a shot, let me know if its what you need or not, so if its not I can update the answer!

First of all I see u are accepting `POST` request!

```
@app.route('/<username>/<question_number>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def ask_questions(question_number):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        do_stuff_like_checking_the_answer_and_redirect_to_new_page_or_reload_the_same_page()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        questions = get_all_questions()
        return render_template("riddle1.html", question=questions, question_number=question_number)
```

Since u are sending the whole list to the template and using array indexes u need to use something like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>Welcome, {{ username }} to RiddleMeThis!</h1>

    <p>{{ question[question_number][0] }}</p>

    <form method="POST">
        <label for="guess">Answer:</label>
        <input type="text" id="guess" name="guess">
        <button>Enter</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

About the url, I guess your are using it to return to the question page if the answer wasn't correct, all u need to do is `from flask import url_for`, and use it like

`url_for('ask_questions', question_number=1)`

You can use any other number, u can even have the number as a variable

Comment: That's fantastic, really set me on the right track actually!

So my next step I think is to make a new URL endpoint which handles the user's form data and checks the answer. If correct it can redirect to the question endpoint and just +1 to the <question_number> variable... Sorry, thinking out loud!!

Thanks so much for you help

Comment: @joester110 So was my answer what you wanted or .. !? You can simply create another view that only accepts `POST` method, instead of sending the form data to same view, u have to send it to new view, then on other view, decide what you wanna do, Its better to use a CSRF token on form btw.